# How to disable InputChip if i select one InputChip in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
  Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            InputChip(
              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
                child: Text('A'),
              ),
              label: Text('Account Wallet'),
              selected: false,
              onSelected: (selected) {

              },
            ),
            Text("Or"),
            InputChip(
              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
                child: Text('P'),
              ),
              label: Text('Paytm Wallet'),
              selectedColor: Colors.orange,
              selected: true,
              onSelected: (selected) {

              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I am trying to make two input chips with that code but I am not able to do it how to change the color when it is selected or deselected, how to change the color if anyone is selected, and disable the second one. Means if I select the PaytmWallet the Account Wallet automatically will be disabled.

Comment: Do you want to completely disable the other chip? Meaning you don't want to allow selection?

Comment: yes if i select the one chip then disable the another chip, yepp I don't want to allow selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 bools to store the selected value of each input:

```
bool accountSelected = false;
bool paymentSelected = false;

Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    InputChip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
        child: Text('A'),
      ),
      label: Text('Account Wallet'),
      selected: accountSelected,
      selectedColor: Colors.orange,
      onSelected: !paymentSelected
          ? (val) {
              setState(() {
                accountSelected = true;
              });
            }
          : null,
    ),
    Text("Or"),
    InputChip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
        child: Text('P'),
      ),
      label: Text('Paytm Wallet'),
      selectedColor: Colors.orange,
      selected: paymentSelected,
      onSelected: !accountSelected
          ? (val) {
              setState(() {
                paymentSelected = true;
              });
            }
          : null,
    ),
  ],
)
```

You can use `disabledColor` on the InputChip to change the color.